# How to mount ext4 in Windows in read-write mode permanently?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning

I have dual boot model that is looking like that:

```
HDD (/dev/sda)
- Partition 1 NTFS (Windows stuff)
- Partition 2 NTFS (Windows itself)
- Partition 3 NTFS (Looks like windows stuff too)
- Partition 4 EXT4 (Used by linux as additional space)
SSD (/dev/sdb) (Loader)
- Partition 1 SWAP
- Partition 2 EXT4 (Linux)
```

I already have fstab rule for `sda/partition 4` in ubuntu
Now I want to mount the same partition in windows automatically on boot

I tried to use `Ext2 Volume Manager` application and I think it could be good if it could mount partitions in RW instead of RO at the same drive. I can easily set up `SSD/Partition 2` to boot in RW but not `HDD/Partition 4`
Windows hybernation is turned off permanently

[image]
[image]

p.s. I don't need temporary reading things like `Diskinternals linux reader` and similar. I want free/opensource solution to work with the partition as with native filesystem

Comment: This is generally *not* a good idea. Windows is fairly likely to damage ext*x* partitions when writing, AFAIK. There are tools such as Disk Genius and MiniTool Partition Wizard to give temporary access, though.